# Springer Nature: Table placement with [H] parameter error

Tags: tables, springernature

I am using the Springer Nature's `sn-basic` document class. I have lots of figure and tables. Whenever I am using `\begin{table}[H]` I am getting `LaTeX Error: \begin{tableorg} on input line 603 ended by \end{table}.`
and `LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 603 ended by \end{document}.`#

Here is the preamble.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\jyear{2022}%

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\raggedbottom
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentclass `sn-jnl.cls` file:

Replace the lines 1339--1348:

```
\let\tableorg\table%
\let\endtableorg\endtable%

\renewenvironment{table}[1][]%
{\begin{tableorg}[#1]%
\tablebodyfont%
\renewcommand\footnotetext[2][]{{\removelastskip\vskip3pt%
\let\tablebodyfont\tablefootnotefont%
\hskip0pt\if!##1!\else{\smash{$^{##1}$}}\fi##2\par}}%
}{\end{tableorg}}
```

with

```
\let\tableorg\table%
\let\endtableorg\endtable%

\renewenvironment{table}[1][]%
{\tableorg[#1]%koleygr: Change here
\tablebodyfont%
\renewcommand\footnotetext[2][]{{\removelastskip\vskip3pt%
\let\tablebodyfont\tablefootnotefont%
\hskip0pt\if!##1!\else{\smash{$^{##1}$}}\fi##2\par}}%
}{\endtableorg}%koleygr: Change here
```

**EDIT *Without touching cls file*:**

Add this in your preamble (before loading `float` package)

```
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]%
{\tableorg[#1]%
\tablebodyfont%
\renewcommand\footnotetext[2][]{{\removelastskip\vskip3pt%
\let\tablebodyfont\tablefootnotefont%
\hskip0pt\if!##1!\else{\smash{$^{##1}$}}\fi##2\par}}%
}{\endtableorg}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. When I submit the paper, isn't this a concern that I am changing the class file?

Comment: Possibly it will be... but if you tell them that they have a bug in their code and this is the fix they will possibly accept it... Also, I will upload another fix later (I think that I can do it) that will not require this change in their documentclass ... but if they fix it it will be much better

Comment: Answer updated. Happy TeXing!

Comment: thanks a lot. It is working. The Springer Nature template is so bugggggggy.

Comment: Ask them to hire me to improve it hahahhaa

Comment: @PrakharSharma by loading the float package you are already changing the intention of the class, as float redefines internals. So better ask them first if they like non-floating tables.

Comment: you are awesome :)