# LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. and LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 437 ended by \end{tableorg}

Tags: tables

```
\linespread{1.6}
\begin{table}[Htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
model& MMSE\\ \hline
Outcome Network &   0.0794\\\hline
+Propensity Score Encoder & 0.0654\\\hline
+Propensity Dropout & 0.0593\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{MMSE of each component}
\label{tab:42result}
\end{table}
```

The table is after a piece of words in `\subsection`, and i got two errors, **\caption outside float** and  **\begin{table} on input line 437 ended by \end{tableorg}.**
the related :

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,fleqn]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,boxed,commentsnumbered,algo2e,vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

---

the errors info:

```
! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ...

l.446 \caption  {MMSE of each component} You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit. ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \sf@endfloatbox ...gefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup  \color@endbox l.448 \end{table}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'. ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup

l.448 \end{table}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

2. 

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 437 ended by \end{tableorg}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ...

l.448 \end{table}

Your command was ignored. Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command, or <return> to continue without it. Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [] Overfull \hbox (9.8355pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 16 \OT1/cmr/m/it/10 Learning Counterfactual Outcome Of MOOC Mul tiple Learning Behaviors [] Overfull \vbox (1.44444pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [] [16] No file sn-article.bbl. Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations. Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line
511. Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

---

When i use `\begin{table}[H]`,another error instead the first:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 437 ended by \end{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.476 \end{document}

Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line
476.
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
Overfull \hbox (9.8355pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 Learning Counterfactual Outcome Of MOOC Multiple
Learning Beh
aviors \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 17
[]
Overfull \vbox (1.44444pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[]
```

Comment: again, please do not post disconected fragments, post a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: Additionally does a float placement of `Htb` even make sense? `H` is normally used alone as it does not allow the float to float. And where does `sn-jnl.cls` come from? It is not on CTAN

Comment: line endings need to be shown in error messages so use a code bock not a `>` quote. As dalif says `[Htb]` is wrong,  But if that is not the cause please add an example document.

Comment: Just for information, the `sn-jnl.cls` is the Springer Nature Journal class that can be downloaded on their [author support website](https://www.springernature.com/fr/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)

Comment: When i use the 'H' instead of 'Htb', the errors change. I use the template from the Springer Nature Journal.

Comment: you have still not posted any code that generates the eerror to allow people to debug it

Comment: The solution is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654920/113546